# Can't mount external hdd

Tags: debian, mount, hard-disk

I am using Debian and I'm using Windows as well (much longer).

I loaded a external disk on Windows but when trying to mount on linux again I keep getting the same error:

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
Unprivileged user can not mount NTFS block devices using the external FUSE
library. Either mount the volume as root, or rebuild NTFS-3G with integrated
FUSE support and make it setuid root. Please see more information at
http://tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#unprivileged
```

Tried mounting with command line but got another error:

```
:~$ sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /media
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
```

Comment: What about `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /media`, or `sudo mount -o ro -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /media`?

Comment: Has your disk been mounted elsewhere? It may have already been automatically mounted by the system. Look at the output of the `mount` command on its own or post it here if you are unsure. Also, was Windows shut down cleanly the last time you used it?

Comment: Please refer to the below link

http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Hard_Disk_Formatting/Partitioning_and_Mounting_in_Debian_Linux

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution I've pieced together from various sources (namely http://tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#unprivileged) - it's rather long, but it works at least on wheezy and jessie:

1. open terminal
2. donwload source:

   ```
   $ apt-get source ntfs-3g
   ```
3. enter package source directory (name may vary)

   ```
   $ cd ntfs-3g-2014.2.15AR.2
   ```
4. change package config to use internal `fuse`:

   ```
   $ sed -i -e "s/--with-fuse=external/--with-fuse=internal/" debian/rules
   ```
5. build package

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get build-dep ntfs-3g
   $ fakeroot debian/rules binary
   ```

   sometimes building fails, so clean and run again - it should work now:

   ```
   $ fakeroot debian/rules clean
   $ fakeroot debian/rules binary
   ```
6. install created package (again, name may vary)

   ```
   $ sudo dpkg -i ../ntfs-3g_2014.2.15AR.2-1+deb8u2_amd64.deb
   ```
7. now you have to configure `ntfs-3g` as setuid (this IS dangeous and you SHOULD know what you're doing):

   ```
    $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure ntfs-3g
   ```

   and answer `yes` to setuid, or if it doesn't work, do it manually:

   ```
    $ chmod 4755 $(which ntfs-3g)
   ```
8. if you do not want to repeat all this after every debian upgrade, set `ntfs-3g` on hold:

   ```
    $ echo "ntfs-3g hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
   ```

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer in this forum, [link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.debian.user/432163), which recommends to mount the drive as root:

```
mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```